# Possible to have nested inserts in Postgres 8.4?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I'm trying to import data into an inventory type database. Here's what I have for the tables (truncated for brevity):

```
create type hostrole as enum ('Physical', 'Virtual', 'Hypervisor', 'Other');

create table host (
  id serial primary key,
  hostname varchar(40),
  role hostrole
);

create table interface (
  id serial primary key,
  name varchar(20),
  host int references host(id) on delete cascade,
  mac macaddr
);
```

I know I can nest a `select` into an `insert` statement, my question is whether I can nest an `insert` into an `insert` (and if so, how to do so). Here's the statement I'm trying to run:

```
insert into interface 
  (name, 
   mac, 
   host) 
     values 
  ('eth0', 
   '00:50:56:9d:34:d4', 
   (insert into host (hostname, hostrole) values ('foobar', 'Virtual') returning id)
);
```

The error comes up at the "into" of the nested insert. Can I do this in one shot, or do I have to make separate queries to do this insert?

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to do something like this with a writable CTE:

```
WITH i AS (
   INSERT INTO host (hostname, hostrole) VALUES ('foobar', 'Virtual') RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO interface (name, mac, host)
SELECT 'eth0', '00:50:56:9d:34:d4', id
FROM i
```

(untested, but it should be something like that)

Writable CTE is in PostgreSQL 9.1 and up.

Comment: Drat. I wish I could use 9.1 or later. I'm kinda stuck with 8.4.

Comment: On 8.4 there is no way to do it, sorry. But if you're on 8.4, there are other reasons to start looking at an upgrade - http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ - you've got less than a years "lifetime" left in that version.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already looking at upgrading the OS entirely. I'm stuck at 8.4 because I'm stuck at RHEL 5, trying to start moving to RHEL 7 in early 2014.

Comment: While I realize there can be policies, RHEL5 does i no way limit you to 8.4. See http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/ in the section about yum.

Comment: The policies limit me to what's available through a restricted set of repositories. In this case, I accept that these policies are reasonable and acceptable for the environment I'm in. So yes, I am restricted to PostgreSQL 8.4 currently.

Comment: @John Well, I wonder what policy could dictate being stuck on an ageing system... 9.1 had some problems initially IIRC but it is rather stable these days.

Comment: No reason to use 9.1 also, as 9.2 is newer, better and stable... BTW, if you can't use repositories, install it by source code, it is really easy...

Answer (score 7):

In 8.4 you could do this by wrapping the inner inserts in a function.  Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_host(in_hostname text, in_hostrole text)
RETURNS INT LANGUAGE SQL AS
$$
   INSERT INTO host (hostname, hostrole) VALUES ($1, $2);
   SELECT id FROM host WHERE hostname = $1;
$$;
```

Then you can still do something like:

```
insert into interface 
(name, mac, host) 
 values 
('eth0', '00:50:56:9d:34:d4', insert_host('foobar', 'Virtual'));
```